# stat_summary: Including single observations into aggregating function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to "force" an aggregating function in stat_summary to calculate an output value for single observations:

```
set.seed(1)
value <- c(rep(1:6, each = 3), 7:8)
rel_freq <- sample(x = seq(0, 1, 0.1), size = length(value), replace = TRUE) 
example_df <-  data.frame(value, rel_freq) 

require(ggplot2)  
ggplot() + 
  stat_summary(data = example_df,
               mapping = aes(x = as.character(value), y = rel_freq),
               fun.data = mean_se) 

# Warning message: Removed 2 rows containing missing values (geom_pointrange)
```

[image]

Now what happened here (IMO) is that `ggplot` removed observations 7 and 8 because the aggregating function in `stat_summary` doesn't work with single observations? But is there a way to force an output here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your own little function that extends `mean_se` to handle the case where the length of x equals 1.

```
mean_se_tjebo <- function (x, mult = 1) {
  x <- stats::na.omit(x)
  se <- mult * sqrt(stats::var(x)/length(x))
  mean <- mean(x)
  if(length(x) != 1) {
    data.frame(y = mean, ymin = mean - se, ymax = mean + se)
  } else {
    data.frame(y = mean, ymin = mean, ymax = mean)
  }
}
```

Now the plot looks as follows

```
ggplot() + 
  stat_summary(data = example_df,
               mapping = aes(x = as.character(value), y = rel_freq),
               fun.data = mean_se_tjebo)
```

[image]

Comment: @Tjebo Glad to help.